# Complicated Trigonometry Math Problem (for me at least)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

How would I calculate the angle in the picture (REF 94.61) with all of the defined parameters (highlighted in red).

[image: Image of the problem shape with defined parameters]

I have tried to use right angled triangle everywhere in this shape, but I just could not work it out.

Also note that the 10mm long legs are joined to the same line, which is the line angled 94.61 degrees from the large leg. Furthermore, the thickness of these legs (1mm in this example) are equal, but can change (i.e. if one is 3mm other needs to be 3mm).

Note: All of the parameters can change, see image with different inputs/ouput here: [Shape with different inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl1by.png)

Comment: Are both the legs the same size or it was your intention to put each arrow differently?

Comment: Both of the legs are the same size 10mm long (measured from inside) and 1mm thick; however, they dont have to be, the 94.61 degree is just the result of the parameters (highlighted in red) used in this examples, thats why Im try to find the algebraic equation.

Also, thickness of these legs (1mm) are always equal.

Comment: Is the 10.00 the size of the longer side or the size of the shorter side of the leg?

Comment: Ohh I see what you mean now (I think). Leg touching the "ground" is 10mm, leg lifted from the ground is 10mm long and is 10 mm offset from the "ground", but all of these 3 parameters can be changed, so they could be 9,8 and 7mm for example.

Comment: I have added another image to highlight that the inputs can change, but like I said before the thickness of both legs are equal (but can be changed, but can never be different).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution.  Here is a picture.

[image: picture]

$AE', AG, EF, DD'$ are horizontal, $CD', CG, DF, EE'$ are vertical, $AB$ is at angle $\pi/4 = 45^\circ$, $\angle ABC$ is a right angle.  I will solve for angle $\theta=\angle DEF = \angle CAG$.  Then the angle we want is $3\pi/4-\theta$.

In the original problem, we are given lengths $AB=18, DD'=1,AE'=1, DF=10$.  Using these, we get:

$\angle ACB = \theta+\pi/4$, so $AC = 18 \csc(\theta+\pi/4)$ and
$CG = 18 \sin\theta\csc(\theta+\pi/4)$.

In right triangle $\triangle D D' C$ we have $DD'=1$ so $CD' = \tan(\theta)$; similarly $EE'=\tan(\theta)$.

Subtracting, $DF = CG - CD' - EE' = 18 \sin\theta\csc(\theta+\pi/4) - 2\tan(\theta)$

The problem to solve is
$$
18 \sin\theta\csc(\theta+\pi/4) - 2\tan(\theta) = 10
$$

This has two solutions,

[image: graph]

The one near $\pi/4$ is
$$
\theta = -\arctan \frac{\left( 3\,\sqrt {2}-9+\sqrt {89-54\,\sqrt {2}}
 \right) \sqrt {2}}{2}
$$
(We have to solve a quadratic equation for $\tan\theta$.)

We get $\theta \approx 0.7049$ so the angle we want is 
$3\pi/4 - \theta \approx 1.6513 \approx 94.6106^\circ$.

---

In the other example, things are the same except $DF=13$ by subtracting.
We must solve
$$
18 \sin\theta\csc(\theta+\pi/4) - 2\tan(\theta) = 13
$$
The solution near $\pi/4$ is
$$
-\arctan \frac{\left( 15\,\sqrt {2}-36+\sqrt {1538-1080\,\sqrt 
{2}} \right) \sqrt {2}}{8} 
$$

We get $\theta \approx 1.1145$, so $3\pi/4-\theta \approx 1.2417 \approx 71.146^\circ$

Comment: I guess this function cant be solved without numerical approach? What I am trying to obtain is the algrebraic equation for it, as in make (theta) subject.

Comment: I added the closed form versions of the solution.

Comment: How did you make "Theta" the subject for that equation?

Comment: Also, bit off topic, but how did you learn all of that stuff, could you recommend any book or something?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it: draw a line thru the lowest point parallel to the ground. You will get right isosceles right triangle with legs equal to $\frac{18}{\sqrt{2}} \approx 12.73$. Now draw line thru $10$ and $20$ marks parallel to the ground. You will get a right triangle with legs $60-12.73-1-1$ (horizontal leg) and $10$. Now you can find $\tan \alpha=\frac{10}{45.27}$. The angle of interest is $180°-45°-\arctan{\frac{10}{45.27}} \approx 122.54 °$

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I dont quite understand it. "Lowest point parallel to the ground", point cant be parallel to the line? Im not seeing what you're seeing, and your answer is different to mine (on the image), or I might be missing something.